# Azure Android: Uploading a Photo to BLOB Storage error

Tags: android, azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a selected from from my android device to my Azure Blob Storage. First I select an image from my gallery and then it uploads the image to my Cloud Storage. But it throws this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/images/media/126310: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Here's my code:

```
 Button choosePhoto = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.choosePhotoBtn));
            choosePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
                }
    });   

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 1) {

                Log.d("Testing", "Uploading");

                // currImageURI is the global variable I'm using to hold the content:// URI of the image
                currImageURI = data.getData();
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.photoPath);
                tv.setText(currImageURI.toString());

                new MyTask().execute();
            }
        }
    }



    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Here starts the code for Azure Storage Blob
            try{
                // Retrieve storage account from connection-string
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

                // Create the blob client
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

                // Get a reference to a container
                // The container name must be lower case
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("photos");

                // Create the container if it does not exist
                container.createIfNotExists();

                // Create a permissions object
                BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

                // Include public access in the permissions object
                containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);

                // Set the permissions on the container
                container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);

                // Create or overwrite the "myimage.jpg" blob with contents from a local file
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("image_1055026155.jpg");
                File source = new File(currImageURI.toString());
                blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source.getAbsolutePath()), source.length());
                Log.d("Testing", "Done");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("SARATH", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It seems like it can't find my file? What do yall think is wrong?

Comment: Based on the error message, I think the file you're trying to upload doesn't exist or perhaps just doesn't exist in the directory you're looking for it in.

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft It exists. I tried 10 other images and they do too. Have you got a code sample that you have used maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately a sample from me would only show me using my file system which would not really help you with yours. See the answer below for some ideas of what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest debugging by adding a couple lines after the File source = new File(...) line that check for existence (exists) and maybe then try creating that file (createNewFile). See the [File API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) for more info. You can then see where the new file is created which will give you an idea of where the file system is actually looking.

Also, while the code you have that gives a FileInputStream is valid, it may be easier to use the built-in uploadFromFile method in the storage library.